# New tag request [gitworkflow]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

The branching strategy the git.git project uses is called "gitworkflow". The man page is here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows#_managing_branches

I'd like to create a tag on Stack Overflow for questions related to this. The first question I'd like to tag with this is my own here:

[Git log `--first-parent`, WITH just the first merged commit from the second parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55536525/git-log-first-parent-with-just-the-first-merged-commit-from-the-second-pare)

Answer (score 4):

You have more than enough reputation to [create tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) on your own.

Also, the tag [git-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-workflow) already exists.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't see that.